# not works yahoo-oauth2 authorization in django social auth

Tags: django, yahoo-api, python-social-auth

i want to be authorized on the site with yahoo account. In django app i have django-social-auth==0.7.28, Django==1.10.5 on Python3.5.

my settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    ....
    'social_core.backends.yahoo.YahooOAuth2',
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_YAHOO_OAUTH2_KEY = 'my_key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_YAHOO_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'my_secret'
```

and my template

```
<p><a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'yahoo-oauth2' %}"><b> Yahoo</b></a></p>
```

All works, but when i enter my login, then email,
i recieve this error
[image]

What it is means? And what can i do? 
Help please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all django-social-auth is deprecated and you should move to [social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django).

Also you should check if you have configured properly Yahoo app in the Yahoo Developer Center. Most APIs like that have some restrictions to the user-specified domains and URLs. Check if it is correct.

[Social app django](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/yahoo.html#yahoo-oauth2) documentation is pretty outdated, but still can be used. Also check issues on the project github (link above).

Comment: backend which interacts with api is social_core it's part of python-social auth ecosystem. And other social API works good(facebook, twitter, google). And first request is good. But Yahoo API don't sent response correct. May be it is domain name in app settings. I locally use mydomain.com. So how to test Yahoo API locally?